# Make changes of wp-db.php file persistent against updates

Tags: database, core-modifications

I've added `$this->query("set session wait_timeout=600");` into `wp-includes/wp-db.php` file because of "MySQL has gone away" errors in every query and I need to find some way to do the changes in file persistent (I suppose update of WordPress rewrites `wp-db.php` file).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to modify core WP files. Figure out the issue with the MySQL server dying: it's going to be lack of good server configuration, a (very) bad quality host or a theme that is very database query-intensive.

Fixing the underlying cause of the database server errors is the best thing to do in the long run; hacking core files is a bad, temporary fix.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, WordPress overwrites its own Core file on update. That is why you don't hack them.

I am not exactly sure where you have inserted that code, but I suspect it may be in several places.

My first though is "talk to your host" or "adjust the global MySQL settings" (if you can). And of course, fix your site. There is almost certainly some poor quality code.

If you really must run an altered database object copy the whole `wp-db.php` file to `wp-content/db.php` and make your edits there. WordPress will load the altered file instead. [It is called a "drop-in"](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/). This is a last resort. It really shouldn't be necessary on a decent host with decent code, and using  a "drop-in" for this kind of hack is probably an abuse of the concept.

Comment: "drop-in" files are very interesting; I didn't know that.